# Regex matching words between whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that matches the following (the brackets indicate I want to match this section, they are not there in the actual string to be matched!):

```
More Words:
    6818 [some words]       641 [even more words]
```

I tried it with following:

`(?<=[0-9]+\s)[a-z\s]+(?!\s{2,})`

To say it in literals; "Match all words including the whitespace between them that come one space after 1 or more digits and before 2 or more whitespaces" but it selects all whitespaces as well as it sometimes strips out the last letter of a word (wtf?)

Comment: so what should be your final output?

Comment: Many regex implementations do not support look-behinds that have no obvious length, or even a variable length, so chances are the the `[0-9]+` inside `(?<=[0-9]+\s)` is illegal. So, my question (besides the one ghostdog already asked): what language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. I'm using C# which according to wiki and it's own documentation supports both, look-behind and look-aheads.

My final output should be the parts marked with [] in the example above. (Of course the brackets are not included, would be too easy then, eh? :( )

Comment: I didn't question whether it would support look behinds, but look-behinds that support "variable-widths" inside them. I'm not sure if C# supports that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=\d\s)([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+`

This one did the trick! Don't ask how I came on that one, just fuzzing around... Still, you were a great help :)

To clarify this regex, short explanation:

```
1: (                open group 1
2:  ?<=\d\s         look, if a digit followed by a whitespace are before group 2
3: )                close group 1
4: (                open group 2
5:  [a-zA-Z]+\s     match any words / letters that are followed by a whitespace
6: )*               close group 2 and let it repeat or not even be there
7: [a-zA-Z]+        match any words / letters and let them repeat one or more times
```

long story short, the regex doesnt try to match words between an amount of whitespaces but matches anything between a digit/whitespace and a word/letter :)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
(?<=[0-9]+\s)([a-z]+\s)*[a-z]+(?!\s{2,})
```

@Bart: I removed the brackets.

Explanation: This will select all words followed by a single whitespace (if they exist) plus the last word not followed by a whitespace (which is mandatory)

Comment: Many regex implementations do not support look-behinds that have no obvious length, or even a variable length, so chances are the the `[0-9]+` inside `(?<=[0-9]+\s)` is illegal.

Comment: Works quite well, but now I get the strange behaviour, that sometimes the last letter of a word isn't selected, e.g.:

[some word]s and [even more word]s

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
[0-9]+\s([a-z \s]+)\s\s
```